# Title punctuation stripper behaves differently when asking a new question vs. editing a question

Tags: bug, title

Observe this revision history: https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/31758/revisions

You will notice that the OP was able to post the following title:

```
Is Kirby a baby in the original Kirby: Right Back At Ya!?
```

When I edited the post to fix the tags, the auto-punctuation-stripper turned it into this:

```
Is Kirby a baby in the original Kirby: Right Back At Ya?
```

Notice the missing exclamation point. I was unable to edit the exclamation point back in, so I instead enquoted the title "Kirby: Right Back At Ya!" to defeat the punctuation stripper.

The problem here is that the punctuation stripper behaves differently depending on whether you're asking a new question or editing an existing one.

---

That said, I tried to end the title of this post with a !? when I posted it, and the stripper turned it into just a ? (so I edited the ? out afterwards), so maybe this is site-specific behavior, or maybe there's another explanation for what we're seeing in the revision history linked above.